# New packages installed with pip not recognised by VSCode

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, pip

i'm having issues with installing packages through pip. Im doing the standard pip3 install "package name" and from what i can see there arent any stand out errors that indicate im doing something wrong, however when i try to import the packages into a python file in VSCode it isnt recognised, any ideas of what could be wrong? Here is a screenshot of an example installation. Thanks in advance. [example installation of python package with pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KHC4.png)

Comment: What exactly happens? How do you know the package is not recognized by VSCode?

Comment: When trying to import the package, the package name is underlined in yellow with the comment "package name cannot be resolved"?

Comment: Try a virtual environment

Comment: You may need to select the correct interpreter for your workspace. [See](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: Try doing the `pip install package_name` from VS Code's inbuilt terminal

Answer (score 1):

This problem may be caused by inconsistency between your python interpreter and python package installation.

1. Use shortcuts "ctrl+shift+P" and type "Python: Select interpreter".
2. Choose your python interpreter in the list.
3. Reinstall the package in terminal and try to run your code.

If you are using a virtual environment, make sure the environment is activated and install it using the conda command.